# Chrome extension intercept ajax requests to specific endpoints to modify form data

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to modify ajax requests to a specific endpoint on a webpage?

For example, all requests on wwww.example.com that go to `/should_intercept` will trigger a function that can modify the form data? If so, how can I intercept specific requests?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it.

You can create a [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) on [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) and inject it as a script into the page, to override original XMLHttpRequest. And inside your implementation of the Proxy, you will be able to handle requests as you want.

Comment: thanks, do you have any resources to point me to? would be helpful. or just psuedo code

Comment: You could look into [this example](https://gist.github.com/valotvince/ef8f70e8a565fbd723a7a0c806709a55) how to implement a Proxy.
For the client script, it just injection script tag into the page body with this code, and it will execute inside of the page context.